# django get json values

Tags: python, json, django

Hello i get json data back and would like to get the key, value pairs but i have been unable to do so. I work with python 3.4 and Django 1.8. 
Would someone please help me to get the key, value pairs?

for example i would like to access all of the values inside Value only from page_fans_add_unique

```
r = requests.get('https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/some/insights?access_token='+access_token.token)  

content = r.json

get {'paging': {'next': 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/some/insights?access_token=&since=1434458194&until=1434717394', 'previous': 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/some/insights?access_token=&since=1433939794&until=1434198994'},


{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "511524265623184/insights/page_fan_adds_unique/day", 
      "name": "page_fan_adds_unique", 
      "period": "day", 
      "values": [
        {
          "value": 2, 
          "end_time": "2015-06-14T07:00:00+0000"
        }, 
        {
          "value": 4, 
          "end_time": "2015-06-15T07:00:00+0000"
        }, 
        {
          "value": 4, 
          "end_time": "2015-06-16T07:00:00+0000"
        }
      ], 
      "title": "Daily New Likes", 

    },
```

Comment: Please format your code so the wrapping is minimized.

Comment: Which keys? Which values?

Comment: Well i would like to access the actual data, the values inside value and put that in a new variable

Comment: We don't know what is your __actual data__, you have to provide an example of expected output. And keeping the example smaller is always appreciated.

Comment: Expected output would be each value inside values

Comment: requests.json() is a method not an attribute. you need to call it like so: `content = r.json()` to get a dictionary out of it. If you do `print(content)` with what you have now you should see something similar to this `<bound method xxxxxxx of <xxxxxxx object at 0x0000000002E8E0F8>>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to call `r.json()` to actually return the value. If you're wanting to iterate over the `data` key:

```
for data in content.get('data'):
    for k, v in data.items():
        if k == 'values':
            try:
                print(data[k][0])
            except KeyError:
                print('Nothing')
```

Example output from my Terminal given your data:

```
>>> content = {
...   "data": [
...     {
...       "id": "511524265623184/insights/page_fan_adds_unique/day", 
...       "name": "page_fan_adds_unique", 
...       "period": "day", 
...       "values": [
...         {
...           "value": 2, 
...           "end_time": "2015-06-14T07:00:00+0000"
...         }, 
...         {
...           "value": 4, 
...           "end_time": "2015-06-15T07:00:00+0000"
...         }, 
...         {
...           "value": 4, 
...           "end_time": "2015-06-16T07:00:00+0000"
...         }
...       ], 
...       "title": "Daily New Likes"
...     }
...   ]
... }
>>> for data in content.get('data'):
...   for k, v in data.items():
...     if k == 'values':
...       print(data[k][0])
... 
{'end_time': '2015-06-14T07:00:00+0000', 'value': 2}
```

Comment: Tried that and get an AttributeError at /
'function' object has no attribute 'get'

Comment: If `content` is a dictionary, that should work. Otherwise, please update your question's code to exactly what `content` is.

Comment: `requests.json()` is a method not an attribute. The OP is setting `content` equal to a reference to the method not the results of calling it.

Comment: Ah. That makes sense then. @DanielKalenda, if you look on the requests home page: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/ you'll see the correction you need to make. Will also note it in my answer.

Comment: @IanAuld is that wrong ? I thought that would format the request?

Comment: `r.text` will return the value, but `r.json` is a *method*, not a property, so you need to call it: `r.json()` to return the value.

Comment: First i want to thank you all for helping me, but i still get all of it but i only want one value or only values. How can i access them?

Comment: What value do you need?

Comment: The first 'value' inside 'values', that it's actually called values is really annoying ^^

Comment: Updated the answer for you

Comment: AttributeError at /
'dict' object has no attribute 'has_header'

Comment: Sorry, my fault. I need more coffee. Updated for you.

Comment: haha no i appriciate the help =) would like to say it's fixed  but ... AttributeError at /
'str' object has no attribute 'get'

Comment: Works for me. Updated my answer with my Terminal output.

Comment: Sorry had a typo inside my function. Thank you very much :)